# Finding a specific html element in a htmlCollection array using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope I worded the title correctly.

Basically I am working in a sharepoint environment. 
On every page of my site I have a sidebar menu with quicklinks to various other pages.

In my sidbar menu which is mostly, if not entirely, generated by SharePoint each menu item in the list is given the class 'menu-item-text'.

Now there is a specific menu item where I want to, using javascript, append text to the existing text. A counter specifically.

So I have something like this..

- MenuItem1
- MenuItem2
- MenuItem3
- MenuItem4
- MenuItem5

and I want to do a calculation on page load and display the numeric results of the calculation to MenuItem3, such as..

- MenuItem1
- MenuItem2
- MenuItem3 **(5)**
- MenuItem4
- MenuItem5

So I assume the way to do this is via javascript. And normally this would be easy if I could target it directly with an ID, but I have a generic class name like this - `<span class="menu-item-text">MenuItem3</span>`

If I use `document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-text')`, i am given back a 'HTMLCollection[389]'

how can i find the 'MenuItem3' item in this array? I assume I can idenitfy by where the 'innerHTML' of the 'menu-item-text' object is equal to 'MenuItem3'.

But unsure how. :)

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here is what the html looks like on the page for the side bar. There is a lot to it...
[image]

Comment: What about using the index? `document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-text')[x]`  BTW, why this question is tagged with jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, A. Wolff. Can you elaborate a little more for me on how to use the index? thanks :) (not sure why my question is getting downvoted so much, but appreciate the comment and assisting in helping)

Comment: Following your posted pseudo code, `document.getElementsByClassName('menu-item-text')[2]` would match the `MenuItem3` if no other element with the `menu-item-text` class are set before in DOM

Comment: David, I added a screenshot of the current HTML that exists. I wasnt sure it was all necessary since I wasnt sure if there was a way to search all 'menu-item-text' objects and find the exact one which has the text I am looking for (ie. 'MenuItem3'). It appears it might not be the case?

Comment: A Wolff, would I not then need to know exactly which ID of the 389 objects in the collection is the one for my menu item? I mean, Im sure I can find it now, but would it not possibly change in the future? Rather search by the text of the object that its assumed location in the array? (thats if I am understanding your suggestion correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well either your class name or html text should be permanent fixed with html.
If **li** text are fixed like '**MenuItem3**' and having class '**menu-item-text**'

then you can do in this way.

```
var element =  $('.menu-item-text:contains("MenuItem3")')
```

otherwise you should allocated **id** to each element based on your requirement.

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IZfpS6ZzNSttcT1F8xjE?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you very much , Riyaj. That seemed incredibly simple, and appears to be a working solution. Thank you for your time. :)